# Find the commit sha of a file with git

Tags: git

I have a folder with an unknown version of a project versioned with git.
The project in the folder (not versioned) have some minor changes that i would introduce in the main versioned project.

I know that the folder project started from a commit a point in the time that is in my versioned project.

I want to find the original starting commit, create a branch, apply the minor changes and then push up everything up to the master.

How can i do this?
I can assume that some files has not changed so, is possible to find a version (commit sha) of a file?

Answer (score 0):

git log --name-only 
will list the files associated with each commit sha.

If you have a particular file in mind you can use 
git log \-- *filename*

e.g. git log \-- main.c

This will show only commits which affect main.c