# Identify the version (SHA) of the last time a specific file was committed

Tags: git, git-log, git-rev-parse

I have a big project with multiple scripts and files all maintained with GIT.  In all those files, there is a document on which I want to print the commit version (SHA) associated with this file.  My Google search gave me:

```
git rev-parse --short HEAD
```

which gives me the HEAD of my project.  However, if my document wasn't included in my last committed change, this version is not the one I want.  [This other stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41147490/find-the-commit-sha-of-a-file-with-git) proposed :

```
git log \-- c.rmd
```

but nothing output from this command in the console.

So, is there a way to output the latest commit SHA associated to one specific file/script? To make it more visual, I want a command that would output `a3` from the specific tree when called for file `c.rmd`.

```
|
L__commit 4 - files a.r, b.r - SHA a4
|
L__commit 3 - files c.rmd - SHA a3
|
L__commit 2 - files a.r - SHA a2 
|
L__commit 1 - files a.r, b.r, c.rmd - SHA a1
```

At the end, I want that version number to be automatically printed in a RMarkdown document in R. So the solution could be either pure git or from an specific R package.

Comment: Note that if the file gets created by cloning the repository, that file is actually *in* the commit you've chosen there. Romain Valeri correctly identified that you want, not this commit, but rather some older commit. That is, you want Git to do its usual thing: start at the *last* commit and work backwards, one commit at a time. At each point, it should *compare* the given file with the copy in the *previous* commit. If the two don't match, you'd like the hash ID of the commit where the parent's copy differs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the SHA of the last commit where file `path/to/myfile.txt` has been modified, go for

```
git rev-list --all -1 -- path/to/myfile.txt
```

For the short SHA :

```
git log --all -1 --pretty=format:"%h" -- path/to/myfile.txt
```

Comment: for package you can use `gitr` or if you git is ssh enabled then `system(git_command)` will also work

Comment: it works, thanks!  Do you know if `git rev-list` as an option similar to the `--short` of `git rev-parse`?